# What is this error code in my tests? I didn't change any code

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have a NodeJS module that uses `express` and `sequelize` basically.

I have automated tests for it that use `mocha`, `mock-require`, `supertest` and `nyc`

This test suite used to run fine, and suddenly on a CI pipeline run, the suite started failing, and I only see this in the logs:

> Process finished with exit code -1066598273 (0xC06D007F)

Anyone have any idea what this could be? I made no changes in the code whatsoever

Comment: You could look into the `Unknown Exception 0xc06d007e error` [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=exception+code+0xc06d007e+unknown+software&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRtdm044HhAhXygM4BHUyIBNMQ7xYIKigA&biw=1920&bih=984)